# OnClick fires for another buttons click event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

For some reason, in my code the `onClick` event for the `disableAccount` button gets activated whenever I click the cancel button. So cancel sets `isEditMode` to false but `disableAccount` sets it back to true thus preventing me from seeing any noticeable change in my UI. This is a next.js project.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextInput from '../Input/TextInput';
import SmallButton from '../Buttons/SmallButton';

const DisableAccountForm = ({t, tc, onSubmit, password, setPassword, isEditMode, setIsEditMode}) => {
  return (
    <label className="block w-full max-w-xl text-2xl mb-4">
      {t("admin")}
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="w-full max-w-xl text-base mt-2">
        <p className="mb-4">
          {t("disableP")}
        </p>
        {isEditMode ?
          <div>
            <p className="mb-4">
              {t("youSureP")}
            </p>
            <p className="text-sm mb-4">
              {t("enterPasswordP")}
            </p>

          </div>
          : null
        }


        {isEditMode ? 
          <label className="flex-col">
            {tc("password")}
            <TextInput 
              placeholder={tc("password")}
              value={password}
              onChange={e=>setPassword(e.target.value)}
              style="m-1"
              required
            />
            <SmallButton 
              type="submit"
              label={tc("submit")}
              color='bg-blue-500' 
              textColor='text-white'
            />
            <SmallButton 
              type="button"
              label={tc("cancel")}
              color='bg-red-500' 
              textColor='text-white'
              onClick={() => {console.log("cancel"); setIsEditMode(false)}}
            />
          </label> 
          :
          <SmallButton 
            type="button"
            label={t("disableAccount")}
            color='bg-blue-500' 
            textColor='text-white'
            onClick={() => {console.log("why"); setIsEditMode(true)}}
          />
        }
      </form>
    </label>
  );
}

export default DisableAccountForm;
```

This is the controller for the code above.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import DisableAccountForm from '../components/DisableAccountForm/DisableAccountForm';

const DisableAccountController = ({t, tc, onSubmit}) => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [isEditMode, setIsEditMode] = useState(false);

  const disableAccount = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("disableAccount");
    setIsEditMode(false);
  }

  return (
    <DisableAccountForm 
    t={t}
    tc={tc}
    onSubmit={disableAccount}
    password={password}
    setPassword={setPassword}
    isEditMode={isEditMode}
    setIsEditMode={setIsEditMode}
    />
  );
}

export default DisableAccountController;
```

SmallButton

```
import React from 'react';

const SmallButton = ({type, label, color, textColor, style, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <button 
      type={type} 
      className={`m-1 ${color} hover:ring-2 rounded-md px-2 py-1 min-w-20 ${textColor} ${style}`}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}

export default SmallButton;
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `<SmallButton>`? Is it actually passing `type` to the underlying `<button>` element? The default for `type` is `"submit"` in HTML, which would make any button inside the form submit it unless that type is being set properly.

Comment: I added the SmallButton code above

Comment: Try moving the two `SmallButton` components out of the password `<label>` element.

Comment: When I move the smallButtons out of the <label> it breaks the Turnery (isEditMode ? do something : do something else). I need a wrapper or I'd have to make seperate Turnery for each button and changing it to a div doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I created a code sandbox with the code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-sm6vl?file=/DisableAccountForm.js:682-731 the cancel button doesn't revert to original view on click as expected. You can view logs there and it seems that for some reason the disableButtons click event is firing. Don't know why

Comment: _"I need a wrapper"_ - You can just wrap the label and buttons in a Fragment with `<>... </>`.

Comment: Tried Fragment and that didn't work either :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

The problem is that the `label` wrapper "clicks" the Disable account button right after the form is switched from edit to display mode. It is the default behaviour of HTML `label` elements. You can solve it by changing the `label` to `div` or fragment or any other wrapper that does not click your buttons.

### Explain In Details

Go to the sandbox you have posted. It opens in display mode (not edit mode). Now, press the text "Admin" on the top. As you can see, the "Disable account" button is pressed - surely not the expected behaviour.

This unexpected behaviour happens for the same reason that the cancel button switches back to edit mode. the whole problem is about the `label` that wraps the form. [The HTML native `label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) attaches the click event of one of the clickable elements nearby or inside the `label` to the content inside the `label`. In-display mode, the `label` detect the "Disable account" button and attach its click event to the whole component.

So, when you click the "cancel" button - the component switches to edit mode, and the `label` wrapper "clicks" the "Disable account" button and switches it back to edit mode. You don't see it when submitting the form, because you prevent the `label`'s default behaviour in `onSubmit` callback. A partial solution for your problem can be to `preventDefault` in the cancel callback too - but it will leave the texts clickable. Another solution might be to change the `label` to `div` or fragment or any other wrapper that does not click your buttons.