# Tailwindcss isn't applying to NextJS Link component

Tags: html, css, next.js, frontend

I have a nextjs frontend project with tailwindcss installed.

In the following example code

```
import Link from 'next/link'

return(
  <div>

     <Link className="text-sm hover:text-gray-600" href="#">Test Link styling</Link>

     <a className="text-sm hover:text-gray-600" href="#">Test Link styling</a> 

  </div>
)
```

When inspecting element on the page, the anchor tag gets styled by tailwindcss but the anchor tag from the Link tag doesn't get any styling.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Does it require changing the tailwindcss configs?

Answer (score 8):

Just put the a tag inside the Link tag without the href, leave href in Link and apply styles to the a tag. Like :

```
<Link className="text-sm hover:text-gray-600" href="#">
    <a className="text-sm hover:text-gray-600">Test Link styling</a>
</Link>
```

source:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Hope this helps and if you get a chance please upvote [OnClick fires for another buttons click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889019/onclick-fires-for-another-buttons-click-event)

Answer (score 1):

I put a button inside it cause idk why it styles better than an `<a>` tag

```
<Link href={"/" + props.id}>
    <button className="text-slate-900">Show Details</button>
</Link>
```

It gets the job done.

Comment: Does this solve the issue of css not getting applied? Otherwise this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: yess, you cant apply styles to the Link tag directly

Answer (score 1):

Use a tag of HTML inside Link tag of next and give href inside Link.

```
<Link href="/support">
   <a className="rounded-lg p-3 duration-300 hover:bg-slate-200">
     Support
   </a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Next **v13** you can directly add `className` to a next `Link` component. https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#nextlink

To get back to the old behavior, you can add the legacyBehavior prop to the Link component:

> Note, when legacyBehavior is not set to true, all anchor tag properties can be passed to next/link as well such as, className, onClick, etc.
> https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because a Next.js `Link` doesn't accept a className property.

If you inspect the resulting HTML of your code, you will see that the resulting `<a>` tag will not have any of your classes on them.

For this to work properly you will need to put an anchor tag as a child to your Link:

```
<Link href="#">
    <a className="text-sm hover:text-gray-600">Test Link styling</a>
</Link>
```

Now next will not create an `<a>` tag for your Link, but instead, pass the `href` property to your existing `<a>` tag.

Comment: i this there is mistake, there are two Closing Tags for `Link` but one Opening Tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `a` tag rather than a `button` tag.
To make it work properly `Link` needs to have `passHref` prop.